# How to get performance counters/metrics in Service Fabric?

Tags: performance, azure, azure-service-fabric, performancecounter, azure-eventhub

I have a stateless service that listens to an EventHub in Service Fabric, and I want to collect performance metrics like the receive latency, and the cpu and memory usage in the nodes in the cluster. What is the easiest way of doing that? I read a lot about that but most examples I saw were showing how to do it with Cloud services which I found quite different from Service Fabric. I also read that Azure Diagnostics could be used to collect performance counters, but I didn't find a clear way of doing it programmatically from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Application Insighs](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-ServiceFabric). It is announced at Build 2017 (See [the last few minutes](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2017/P4168)) and still in beta but it gives you a very good overview of how the services are doing.

I did make a [repo](https://github.com/DeHeerSoftware/Azure-Service-Fabric-Logging-And-Monitoring) myself that integrates Application Insights with Service Fabric. With some coding you can wire it up using my code as a guideline/example. Just for performance counters per node it is relatively easy.

Another option would be using [EventFlow](https://github.com/Azure/diagnostics-eventflow) to collect the performance counter data and send it to wherever you want (there are limited build-in options but it is easy to write a sink yourself)

I am sure there are more but I think Application Insights is your best bet as it supports everything from performance counters (per node) to request telemetry and it is extensible as well.